Expo gives error when using react native firebase for OTP auth
I have developed an Expo app (SDK 51) using React Native Firebase for OTP authentication. However, I'm experiencing an issue when using the build apk-
The OTP does get sent to the users and does get verified too, but then it gives some error. I am also unable to find the reason behind the error as it happens only in the apk build and there is no log to check what is happening.
But when use the development build on the emulator using the command-
npx expo run:android

the verfication works for the test users, and it navigates to the signup page and everything works fine. It seems like the issue is in the apk build which i have built using this command -
eas build -p android --profile preview

I am using the latest versions of the React Native Firebase packages.
I have added the google services json to the root of my project and added the project's sha1 and sha256 keys to firebase.
When I was using trying to use firebase otp auth with the web app packages using the config file everything worked fine. But I was unable to build the project as it was giving an error saying those packages are not supported now.
Any guidance or solutions to resolve these issues would be greatly appreciated.
Here is the code for my login screen -
import React, { useState, useCallback } from 'react';
import { View, Text, TextInput, TouchableOpacity, Alert } from 'react-native';
import { SafeAreaView } from 'react-native-safe-area-context';
import { themeColors } from '../theme';
import auth from '@react-native-firebase/auth';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';
import axios from 'axios';
import i18n from '../i18nConfig';

export default function Login({ navigation }) {
    const [phoneNumber, setPhoneNumber] = useState('');
    const [confirm, setConfirm] = useState(null);
    const [verificationCode, setVerificationCode] = useState('');

    const handleGetOtp = useCallback(async () => {
        try {
            const confirmation = await auth().signInWithPhoneNumber('+91' + phoneNumber);
            setConfirm(confirmation);
            Alert.alert(i18n.t('otpSent'));
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err);
            Alert.alert(i18n.t('error'), i18n.t('otpSendError'));
        }
    }, [phoneNumber]);

    const handleSubmitOtp = useCallback(async () => {
        try {
            await confirm.confirm(verificationCode);
            Alert.alert(i18n.t('authSuccess'));

            await AsyncStorage.setItem('login', 'true');
            await AsyncStorage.setItem('phone', phoneNumber);
            let userType = "supplier";

            const response = await axios.post(
                'api url',
                { phoneNumber, userType }
            );
            navigation.navigate('Home');
        } catch (err) {
            console.log('signup');
            if (err.response && err.response.status === 404) {
                Alert.alert(i18n.t('userNotRegistered'));
                navigation.navigate('SignUp');
            } else {
                Alert.alert(err)
                Alert.alert(i18n.t('error'), i18n.t('authError'));
            }
        }
    }, [confirm, verificationCode, phoneNumber, navigation]);

    return (
    );
}


